# What is it called when you coin a different version of a word that already exists?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, neologisms

I was in a college class the other day and someone was struggling to think of the word "invalidate". Much to my amusement, they landed on "devalidify" instead.

Is there a word or phrase for such a phenomenon, where you coin a word that is technically wrong, but still makes perfect sense?

Comment: Immaginative and ignorant all at the same time. Neologisms have become a hobby for more than a few.

Answer (score 3):

The process of doing this, and the result, is called *back formation*.

You take a perfectly good word, and not knowing the form you want, you form a new word using established rules, which happen to be wrong in the case in point.

An example from *abolish*. The proper noun here is *abolition*, but perhaps on the pattern of forms like *astonishment* or *punishment*, the back-formation *abolishment* is often heard. To me, this is a cause for astonition and the people who do it should suffer punition.

Comment: Interesting! From looking into it, though, it looks like back formation usually results in shortened versions of longer words by throwing away affixes, like _resurrect_ from _resurrection_. Do you think that still applies here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a word exists for this. Perhaps you could call this process "inventing a hypothetical synonym".  So "devalidify" would be a hypothetical synonym for "invalidate".

Side note, you might find this interesting:

[polyseme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyseme) (n.): A word or phrase that has multiple meanings.